# Descomposición en factores primos

Tags: freepascal, números-primos

Estoy comenzando mis pasos en la programación y estoy intentando crear un programa en Pascal que cuando le de un entero positivo me devuelva su descomposición en factores primos en orden creciente. 
Este es el codigo que hice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Efectivamente cuando le doy un entero positivo me hace la descomposición pero no como yo quiero, es decir, da una tira de numeros con un exponente erroneo como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que cuando me haga la descomposicíon. me de los primos con su respectiva multiplicidad, en el caso anterior me gustaría que quede como :

```
100
2^2
5^2
```

Alguien podría decirme que error estoy cometiendo, o como me podrían ayudar? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Recuerda que es mejor pegar el código que poner una imagen. la pregunta siempre será mejor recibida!

Comment: Como indica @RogerTorné, replicar errores o sugerir cambios desde una imagen siempre será mucho más dispendioso. Ayuda a que te ayuden compartiendo codígo y datos relevantes siempre como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Con mi primo logramos llegar a este codigo, lo unico que estaria faltando es que cuando es un numero primo que lo imprima como tal (el codigo te ejecuta n como `n=n^1` y no como `n=n`)

**program Tarea1;**

```
var d,exp,numero : integer;
begin
    writeln('Introduzca el numero: ');
    readln(numero);
    d:=2;
    exp:=0;
    while numero<>1 do
        begin
            if (numero mod d = 0) then 
                begin
                    numero := numero div d;
                    exp:=exp+1;
                     if (numero mod d <> 0) then 
                        begin
                            writeln(d,'^',exp);
                            exp:=0;
                        end
                end                
           else
                begin                      
                    d := d+1;
                end
        end   
end.
```